# My program never ends even after the"break;" statement is fulfilled

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThirdElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList < > ();

        while (true) {
            list.add(name.nextLine());

            if (name.nextLine() == "") {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list.get(2));
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the while loop to break as well as print the desired "get" statement correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the `break` is ever reached?

Comment: You're not executing the break. No other answer.

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Also check - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Is it not being reached because the “” are not enclosed in parentheses? “” —-> (“”)